# Expected: 401 Received: 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I'm currently taking a Node.js Course online and have to do the integration tests required to complete it before deployment. I just tested the GET and POST method and succeeded, however I'm struggling with the PUT method test. I'm using the exact same code the instructor provided for it, but I keep getting the error "Expected: 401  Received: 200".

How do I keep receiving 200 with an empty token??? It doesn't make any sense.

[image]

Here's my code for the PUT method:

```
let server;
// Test all genres
describe("/api/genres", () => {
// Call the function before each test
beforeEach(() => {
   server = require("../../index");
});
// Close the function after each test
afterEach(async () => {
// Prevent genres from duplicating
   await Genre.remove({});

   await server.close();
});
```

// Test PUT Method

```
describe("PUT /:id", () => {
let token;
let newName;
let genre;
let id;

const exec = async () => {
  return await request(server)
    .put("/api/genres/" + id)
    .set("x-auth-token", token)
    .send({ name: newName });
};

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Before each test we need to create a genre and
  // put it in the database.
  genre = new Genre({ name: "genre1" });
  await genre.save();

  token = new User().generateAuthToken();
  id = genre._id;
  newName = "updatedName";
});

it("should return 401 if client is not logged in", async () => {
  token = "";

  const res = await exec();

  expect(res.status).toBe(401);
});
});
```

Comment: If you share the server code (that implements `/api/genres`) I suspect that will help determine the problem.

Comment: Okay I just did.

Comment: No, you posted only test code. It's still unknown why you expect 401 and whether your expectations are correct. But it seems that you at least tried to supply a valid token. Why do you expect it to fail?

Comment: @Dominic There is nothing magic about getting a 401 with a bad/missing token, it's something that your server code would have to explicitly do. So your server code (the express handler you set up for '/api/genres') presumably is not behaving as you think it should. Generally server endpoints will use middleware for authentication, but in a simple tutorial this might be inline. Without seeing that side of things, folks here can't be of much help.